Best method(s) to deploy a Safe with module(s) enabled in one transaction?
Looking for the best way to deploy a new safe, with 1 (maybe 2) modules (these would be deployed) already enabled in one batch transaction. Been diving through the docs and would like some advise to do this:
1.) Use the initializer in the createProxyWithNonce to setup these modules. Thus when setup() is called on the Safe.sol contract, the enableModules(to, data) is targeted, correct? How do I use the to and data to achieve this purpose?
2.) Use the safe-core-SDK function wrapSafeTransactionIntoDeploymentBatch to achieve this.
The main picture of what I am looking to do is when a new safe is deployed, I want the Account Recoverer module (with the recoverer's account embedded in the module) and another module our team is discussing about on-chain protocol fee enforcement to be enabled on that safe that is deployed. Hopefully that makes some sense :-)

Yes this makes sense! I would definitely advise for solution number 2 as it was specifically designed for this purpose. You can simply prepare these transactions and add them to the batch and the SDK will first deploy the Safe, and then execute all the transactions serially.
If for some reason solution 2 is not possible, you can also call the MultiSend contract with the transactions (enabling module and initializing it) as the setup data.
An example could be found here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-modules/blob/main/modules/passkey/test/4337/Safe4337Module.spec.ts#L343-L356.
Hope it helps! Best, Louis

Yes that helps! Is there anywhere you can point me to of some example code that has done this?

I don't have implementation examples but you can take a look at the function definition to see the types of the arguments that it takes: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/ea0d5018a93f294dfd891e6c8963edcb96431876/packages/protocol-kit/src/Safe.ts#L1301

We can't use the SDK for various reasons, so I am back to option 1. How do I encode the initializer for two already deployed modules to be enabled on a newly created safe? So I have two addresses of modules I want to enable. In the setup function, I see the setUpModules function call with to and data inputs. I am stuck at what needs to go here to enable these modules on deployment of a new safe in one txn.

Got it, I just edited my answer above. Could you please mark the question as solved if it answered your problem? Thanks in advance  Louis

Yes this may help! We are wanting to do all this via Solidity, is that even possible? Thanks for all your advice!!

Absolutely, the example I showed was to facilitate the transaction if you are using JS/TS; but the parameters can be sent directly to the Multi-send contract

Still stuck on this. If you don't mind, I will go through the workflow we have now (deployed on Mainnet): From our FE (I'm not a FE guy, we have one though) when a new safe is created, we pass the basics to our GnosisSafeProxyFactory. For the to and data field, we just pass a null address and "". Let's say we have two modules already deployed, what exactly do we pass here? I assume the two modules address, and the data field is what? I also assume it's the function name that we want to call on the modules?

Answering this question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/165874/setupmodulesto-data-help/165885#165885
