`setupModules(to, data)` help
Let's say I have a module deployed at 0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 and from a proxy factory, I want to create a new safe with this module enabled in one transaction/during the setup. The initializer in the createProxyWithNonce is where this would be abi encoded, thus, is the to field address(0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890) and what would be the data field? TIA!

The initializer argument in the createProxyWithNonce is indeed where you would need to pass this information.
The initializer will be passed to the setup function in Safe.sol; it should encode the list of arguments that the setup function will take:
function setup(
        address[] calldata _owners,
        uint256 _threshold,
        address to,
        bytes calldata data,
        address fallbackHandler,
        address paymentToken,
        uint256 payment,
        address payable paymentReceiver
    )

Here, to and data can be used to make a delegatecall during the Safe' setup. This is what we'll use to enable modules:

to will be the address of the SafeModuleSetup.sol contract (depending on the network you can find the address here).
data will be the encoded result of a call to the enableModules function with the module addresses that we want to enable (in your case, the encoded result of ('enableModules', [0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890])).

You can find an example of this setup here.
If some of your module(s) also need configuration, you can use the address of the Multisend.sol contract as the to parameter instead; in this case, the data argument will be the encoded result of a list of transactions:

the first one being the enable module transaction mentioned above (to being be the address of the SafeModuleSetup.sol contract and data being the module addresses)
the second one being the module configuration transaction (here the parameters will depend on your module implementation).

You can find an example of this second scenario here.
I hope that this context gives more information on how to solve the issue. Please let me know if it does not! Best, Louis

I greatly appreciate all the help with this, as I have been banging my head on this for 2-3 months (along with building a module) :-) I've seen my question asked many times before here, in discord, etc and I see very vague and conflicting answers. The first is "just use the to and data in the initializer" is all, and I have seen using the MultiSend.sol like you suggested. Also I was pointed out to use SafeModuleSetup.sol contract to do this.  I will put together a YT video and documentation together once I can figure it out. I'll try this via the MultiSend and report back. TIA!

Thanks for your perseverance on this and apologies for not being accurate in my first answer. I edited it so it can (hopefully) solve your question. Please let me know

Thanks, so in initializer, which I am encoding with abi.encodeWithSelector, I have for the data field this: abi.encodeWithSignature("enableModules(address[]",[MODULE_ADDRESS]), and I still am getting errors. The whole contract code on Sepolia is here if you don't mind taking a look at what I am doing wrong -
